# Display x if x display y if y (bad title I know)

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, so I have some jQuery code that displays an input box if an item with prefix `Blue` from dropdown menu is selected.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select2').on('change', function(event) {
        var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
        var picked_blue = $(opt).text().match(/Blue/i);
        if(picked_blue) {
            $('#text1').show();
        } else {
            $('#text1').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

But what I also need to add is to display something else if any other item from dropdown menu is selected. And what I need to display is another dropdown menu of items.

Comment: what do you want to display ? just put it inside the `else`

Comment: `I also need to add is to display something else` what is that??

Comment: Well then I need to display another dropdown menu.

Comment: Try to add html and css too

Comment: Ok, got the solution :) Thanks everyone for posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't this work for you:

```
if(picked_blue) {
  $('#text1').show();
  $('#text2').hide();
} else {
  $('#text1').hide();
  $('#text2').show();
}
```

where `text1` and `text2` share the position in the DOM, with texts like 'blue' and 'not blue at all', respectively?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put condition in else part of your statement.

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select2').on('change', function(event) {
        var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
        var picked_blue = $(opt).text().match(/Blue/i);
        if(picked_blue) {
            $('#text1').show();
        } else {
            $('#text1').hide();
            if($(opt).text().match(/Red/i))
            {
                  //You code here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

or shortening code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select2').on('change', function(event) {
       selectedVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       switch (selectedVal){
         case 'blue':
            //Your code
            break;
          case 'red':
           //Your code
           break;
          case 'black':
            //Your code
            break;
          default:
            //your code
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Well the problem here is that what you added will only work for items with prefix Red, but I have many others.

Comment: Try to use a map instead `var actions = { 'blue': function() { $text1.show(); }, 'red': function() { /* bla */ } }` with `actions[selected]()`

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting, I got the solution by adding:

if(picked_blue) {
     $('#text1').show();
     $('#text2').hide();
   } else {
     $('#text1').hide();
     $('#text2').show();
   }

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you try with **toggle function in Jquery**

```
$('#text1').toggle();
```